# Django inner join not permitted

Tags: mysql, django, inner-join

I have two tables references one to the field of another, and I can't do an INNER JOIN.

Those are my tables:

```
class VulnerabilitiesCve(models.Model):
    cve = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=14)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    up_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
    type_vul = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    url_cve = models.CharField(max_length=65, blank=True, null=True)


class Products(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    cve = models.ForeignKey('VulnerabilitiesCve', db_column='cve')
```

And this is my query:

```
VulnerabilitiesCve.objects.filter(cve__cve = "CVE-2013-0233");
```

This is the error I get:

```
Unsupported lookup 'cve' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

I have tried changing the cve field to AutoField instead of CharField, but without success, since the cve is a char.

I have other tables, which primary key is an int and I can do INNER JOIN right.

What is the problem¿? Thank you in advance.

Comment: For you to be doing an inner join, you need a foreign key relationship.

Comment: There is a foreign key relationship : cve = models.ForeignKey('VulnerabilitiesCve', db_column='cve')

Comment: But that is the wrong way round. You are trying to query from VulnerabilitiesCve to Products, but the FK is on Products.

Comment: This is the query I want to carry our: ```SELECT * from VulnerabilitiesCve INNER JOIN Products on VulnerabilitiesCve.cve=Products.cve WHERE Products.vendor = "Cisco" and Products.product = "Packet Tracer"```

Comment: If I do the other way round: ```Products.objects.filter(cve__cve = "CVE-2013-0233"); ``` I get this error:: ```Unknown column 'Products.cve_id' in 'field list```

Comment: If you have this error, you must have changed your model recently. If your model fields have changes, that must be reflected on the database level as well. You should use django migration to track your changes, or if you don't care about your data, just drop/recreate the database.

Comment: I haven't changed it, my table is exactly like my model =( Any Idea ¿? I have done ```python manage.py makemigration``` and ```python manage.py migrate``` but... No changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trying to follow the cve field on the cve foreign key relationship. The VulnerabilitiesCve model has a cve field which is not a foreign key relationship.

```
VulnerabilitiesCve.objects.filter(cve__cve = "CVE-2013-0233");
```

I suspect that you either intended to do

```
VulnerabilitiesCve.objects.filter(cve = "CVE-2013-0233");
```

or

```
Products.objects.filter(cve__cve = "CVE-2013-0233");
```